# How to have an object in a class point to its class object in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I want to make a class where one object in that class belongs to a different type of class (though not in a nested way), and the second class object can point back to the class object that contains it.

That's pretty abstract.  Like, let's say I want a class called "Party", which contains objects of the class `Character`.  Let's say that `Party` has an int object called `Total_gold`.  I know I could create that using something like:

```
class Party(object):
    def __init__(self, G1, c1, c2, ...other_stuff_goes_here):
        self.Total_gold = G1;
        self.char1 = Character(c1);
        self.char2 = Character(c2);
        # more stuff to initiate Party

class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, other_stuff_goes_here):
        # stuff to initiate Character
```

Now, let's say I have a function that takes in a Character object, but I want it to alter the `Party` that contains that Character.  For example, let's say I want to have a function, `Spend`, that decreases the Party's `Total_gold`.  Is there a way for `Spend` to take in a Character object, and then access the Party the Character is in?
Something like:

```
def Spend(character, amount): 
    #reduces the Total_gold of the party the character belongs to.
    character.Party.Total_gold -= amount
```

If so, how would I do this?  I assume I need to put something in the `__init__` function, but I don't know how I would do that.  Python doesn't have pointers, right?

If another post has covered this, please let me know. I wasn't sure how to even ask this.

Thank you.

Comment: One option is to make each character store their own gold. Then make `Party.Total_gold` a `@property` that sums all the characters' gold.

Comment: From OO perspective this is a violation of Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP). Making a class Character associate to another class Party (because a Party has Character) is a violation of DIP

Comment: I like your idea about using @property; I didn't know those existed, this taught me something useful.  Thank you.  But, let's say I also needed a way to check if amount was less than Party.Total_gold (so that a Character can spend more gold than it has, but cannot spend more gold than the Party has).  That's not possible to do with @property, right?

Answer (score 1):

Python objects don't internally store any information about being a member of another object, so you'll need to store the instance of Party inside of both Characters. The simplest way to do this is to pass `self` to `Character.__init__`:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, party, other_arg):
        self.party = party
        # Other stuff goes here

class Party:
    def __init__(self, c1, ...):
    self.char = Character(self, c1)
```

Then:

```
def spend(character, amount):
    character.party.total_gold -= amount
```

Comment: Please delete this. This is 100% incorrect design. Either A has B or B has A but both is not a good design.

Comment: My answer achieves exactly what the question is asking. Having circular references is a sign of bad design, but the implementation itself doesn't matter. If I were OP I'd redesign my program so that an object doesn't need to know what contains it (that makes no sense) but that's not my concern so I don't see any reason to delete my answer.

Comment: First, thank you for the answer.  Second, is there a short way to explain what a circular reference is bad design?  I was a computer science major briefly, but much of my coding is self-taught, and I don't think I ever learned why the DIP is so important.  Thank you.

Comment: @Simon one good reason is that circular references will never be garbage collected. But, on a bigger scale, it's good to structure objects in a way that represents data: when a container has a member object, the member represents some data that the container uses for its own purposes. It's usually a sign of bad engineering if containers and members need to know about each other: you could, for example, instead pass some sort of "global state" object around, or move some functionality to the container.